# Kotlin SerializationException in Ktor when Using Type-Safe Request: "Serializer for class 'IsAlive' is not found

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I'm trying to implement a type-safe request in Ktor using Kotlin following the Ktor documentation (https://ktor.io/docs/type-safe-request.html). However, I'm facing a `SerializationException` when I try to call the `isAlive` function in my `Client` class. I have provided my `IsAlive` resource class and my `Client` class which includes all requests for the backend API below.

**Resource Class:**

```
package com.example.client.client_routes

import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.resources.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.resources.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.serialization.*

@Resource("/")
class IsAlive()
```

In my code, I've created a class `IsAlive` annotated only with `@Resource("/")`, but not marked with `@Serializable`. According to the guide, it should work fine, but when I attempt to use it, I encounter a `SerializationException`.

**Client Class:**

```
package com.example.client

import com.example.client.client_routes.IsAlive
import com.example.client.client_routes.User
import com.example.client.model.CreateUser
import com.example.client.model.Login
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.resources.*

expect fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit = {}): HttpClient

class Client {
    private val client = httpClient()

    public suspend fun isAlive(): String {
        val res = client.get(IsAlive())
        return res.bodyAsText()
    }

    public suspend fun createUser(createUserRequest: CreateUser): HttpStatusCode {
        val res = client.post(User()) { setBody(createUserRequest) }
        return res.status
    }

    public suspend fun login(login: Login): HttpStatusCode {
        val res = client.post(com.example.client.client_routes.Login()) { setBody(login) }
        return res.status
    }
}
```

When I call the `isAlive` function, I get the following error message:

```
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'IsAlive' is not found.
Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.
```

I'm currently using the latest versions of Kotlin Multiplatform and Ktor. I'm a bit puzzled because I don't see why a serializer would be needed for `IsAlive` since it doesn't have any properties to serialize. What am I missing here?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you added serialization plugin as per [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/type-safe-request.html#add_serialization)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! Yes, I added `implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-resources:$ktor_version")` to `build.gradle.kts`

Comment: and I added `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")` to `build.gradle.kts` in `commonMain` section

Comment: I'm talking about `plugins` section. check out the link one more time and make sure you follow doc

Comment: thank you I added `kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.21"` to `plugins` section. And Work fine.

Answer (score 1):

add `kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.21"` to `build.graadle.kts` in `plugins` section.